# Error to put PDF files with MS Graph API SharePoint

Tags: pdf, sharepoint, graph

I use the MS Graph API to upload local files in a SharePoint.

It works well with Word or Text files. I can upload them in the SharePoint

**I can also upload PDF files but I cannot open the PDF correctly in SharePoint:**

> "No preview is available for this file".

Of course, it opens normally if I upload manually the PDF in the SharePoint.

Based on what I read on internet, it looks to be an encoding issue but I cannot make it work.
[How to upload pdf file to Sharepoint site using MicrosoftGraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61777127/how-to-upload-pdf-file-to-sharepoint-site-using-microsoftgraph)

I use this request:

PUT ​/sites​/{site-id}​/drive​/items​/{parent-id}:​/{filename}:​/content

Example: `Invoke-WebRequest -Method PUT -Uri "https: XXX sharepoint-online/v1/sites/siteid/drive/items/parentid:/PDFfile:/content" -Headers @{'APIKEY'='XXX';'Content-Type'='multipart/form-data';'Accept'='application/json';'Authorization'="Bearer accesstoken"}  -InFile $pathtopdffile`

Any help/advise please?

Comment: @KJ, thanks for the quick return. I also tried with content-type", "application/pdf" but i get the same error. The pdf file cannot be previewed. I also removed the ;'Accept'='application/json' but i get same issue.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

For files smaller than or equal to 250MB in size, the standard endpoint for SharePoint is:

```
PUT /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/content
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I have used HttpClient to call this endpoint:

```
{
    string uri;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemId)) // replace file
    {
        uri = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{itemId}/content";
    }
    else // new file
    {
        uri = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{parentId}:/{fileName}:/content";
    }
    
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, uri);
    
    httpRequestMessage.Content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
    httpRequestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    
    var httpResponseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
    
    if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        item = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<DriveItem>();        
    }
}
```